# Un-encapsulate refactoring in Eclipse or Intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, intellij-idea

Consider a wrapper class `W`, wrapping `C`, this meaning that for most attributes of `C`, there is a correspondent attribute `A` on `W`, its logic consisting in nothing  more than delegation to `C`'s `A`. This situation can be most precisely depicted with the sketch shown below:

```
class W {
    private C c;

    getX() { return c.getX(); }
    getY() { return c.getY(); }
}
```

The trouble is that I've decided that I wan't to get rid of `getX()`, and I'd prefer to either as a transitory step to put `C c` as public, having all the calling code of `W` do a `w.c.getX()` or `w.c.getY()` or alternatively to put create a `W.getC()`, and have all calls to `getX()` and `getY()` go through it.

What this all boils down is to an "un-encapsulate" refactoring. Is there anything performing this much needed task either in Eclipse or Intellij?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write your new `getC()` method.
2. Rewrite `getX()` to be `return getC().getX()`.
3. Inline `getX()`.

The same goes for `y`.

Comment: Ouoch. I'm a heavy user of the inlining refactoring, yet the idea didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Looking over your answer again, this is the manual version of what [Remove Middleman](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/12/intellij-idea-8-refactorings-remove-middleman/) does automatically.

Answer (score 6):

With IntelliJ you can use the [Remove Middleman](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/12/intellij-idea-8-refactorings-remove-middleman/) refactoring.

Consider:

**Before**:

```
public class W {
    private C c;

    Object getX() { return c.getX(); }
    Object getY() { return c.getY(); }
}

public class C {
    private Object x;
    private Object y;

    public Object getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public Object getY() {
        return y;
    }
}

public class UsesW {
    W w;
    public void useW() {
        Object x = w.getX();
        Object y = w.getY();
    }
}
```

Place your cursor on the declaration of `W.c`. Then choose **Refactor | Remove Middleman**.
The result gets you halfway to where you want to be:

**After**:

```
public class W {
    private C c;

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }
}

/* class C is unchanged */

public class UsesW {
    W w;
    public void useW() {
        Object x = w.getC().getX();
        Object y = w.getC().getY();
    }
}
```

Then you can introduce a variable of type `C` in `UsesW`. Place your cursor over one of the calls to `w.getC()` and inline it: **Refactor | Inline...** (`Ctrl-Alt-N` is the default shortcut), choosing to inline all instances. It'll leave you with this:

```
public class UsesW {
    W w;
    public void useW() {
        final C c = w.getC();
        Object x = c.getX();
        Object y = c.getY();
    }
}
```

Finally getting rid of `W` altogether is something you probably can answer better than me, but now that job became significantly easier.